# Is there any way to fetch Microsoft teams recordings?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

Im trying to fetch teams recording , but im not able to find any api's to get the recording , If there are no api's to get recording , is there any way i can record them ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)?

Comment: Yes, that API doesn't provide any link to download the file. It only contains the details of the call

Comment: Please share your answer if you are able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no such api to download recorded video. The records will be stored in your MS Stream and you can access from Stream.